# Delete xml node from SQL Server 2008 based on attribute value

Tags: xml, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a xml structure in my database like so:

```
<ArrayOfContactDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ContactDetails id="93679d1d-9feb-45d1-8356-e85d188fa34c">
    <contactid>93679d1d-9feb-45d1-8356-e85d188fa34c</contactid>
    <contactname>Name 1</contactname>
    <contactemail>Email 1</contactemail>
    <contactphonenumber>123234234</contactphonenumber>
  </ContactDetails>
  <ContactDetails id="69f54067-edf9-414e-80b6-099ac471dc43">
    <contactid>69f54067-edf9-414e-80b6-099ac471dc43</contactid>
    <contactname>Name 2</contactname>
    <contactemail>Email 2</contactemail>
    <contactphonenumber>123234234</contactphonenumber>
  </ContactDetails>
  <ContactDetails id="93144086-be1c-4f34-a5f7-6e8ac67c2121">
    <contactid>93144086-be1c-4f34-a5f7-6e8ac67c2121</contactid>
    <contactname>Name 3</contactname>
    <contactemail>Email 3</contactemail>
    <contactphonenumber>123456</contactphonenumber>
  </ContactDetails>
</ArrayOfContactDetails>
```

And I'm trying to delete a ContactDetails node based on the ContactDetails id attribute. But I seem to be running into a brick wall.

My SP code is like so

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET tableField.modify('delete //ContactDetails[@id=sql:variable("@contactId")]') 
WHERE tableId = @tableId
```

I get no errors on the page or when debugging/executing the sp and its just driving me insane as to why its not working!!

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What is your `@contactID` variable defined as??

It works on my machine :-) Try this:

```
DECLARE @work TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, XmlContent XML)

INSERT INTO @work VALUES(1, '<ArrayOfContactDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ContactDetails id="93679d1d-9feb-45d1-8356-e85d188fa34c">
    <contactid>93679d1d-9feb-45d1-8356-e85d188fa34c</contactid>
    <contactname>Name 1</contactname>
    <contactemail>Email 1</contactemail>
    <contactphonenumber>123234234</contactphonenumber>
  </ContactDetails>
  <ContactDetails id="69f54067-edf9-414e-80b6-099ac471dc43">
    <contactid>69f54067-edf9-414e-80b6-099ac471dc43</contactid>
    <contactname>Name 2</contactname>
    <contactemail>Email 2</contactemail>
    <contactphonenumber>123234234</contactphonenumber>
  </ContactDetails>
  <ContactDetails id="93144086-be1c-4f34-a5f7-6e8ac67c2121">
    <contactid>93144086-be1c-4f34-a5f7-6e8ac67c2121</contactid>
    <contactname>Name 3</contactname>
    <contactemail>Email 3</contactemail>
    <contactphonenumber>123456</contactphonenumber>
  </ContactDetails>
</ArrayOfContactDetails>')

DECLARE @contactID VARCHAR(50) = '69f54067-edf9-414e-80b6-099ac471dc43'

UPDATE @work 
SET XmlContent.modify('delete //ContactDetails[@id=sql:variable("@contactId")]') 
where id = 1

SELECT * FROM @Work WHERE id = 1
```

The resulting XML I get back comes out without that one `<ContactDetails>` node.

Is your `@contactID` defined as a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` by any chance?? You'd have to convert that to a `varchar` - the XML manipulation stuff all works with strings....

**PS:** another thing I just noticed - this won't work either:

```
DECLARE @YourOriginalContactID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
SET @YourOriginalContactID = '69f54067-edf9-414e-80b6-099ac471dc43'

DECLARE @ContactID VARCHAR(50)
SET @ContactID = CAST(@YourOriginalContactID AS VARCHAR(50))
```

This fails because the `CAST` operations converts the GUID to an UPPERCASE string..... you need to turn it into lower case again:

```
SET @ContactID = LOWER(CAST(@YourOriginalContactID AS VARCHAR(50)))
```

**THEN** it works again! Pretty tricky....

Comment: DOH!! Its was a uniqueidentifier causing a problem. Typical it was something so trival. Thanks, Tom